# Problems using ng2-charts with angular-cli 1.7.3

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to use ng2-charts for a project of my work only that it is not up to date and uses angular-cli 1.7.3 and angular-core 5.2.0, but this version does not recognize the import of the ChartsModule, someone has been able to use this package in such a version old of angular?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5oJ0.png)

Comment: You probably need to be at a much lower version of ng2-charts. I’d try 1.6.0 maybe?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.